# Please help understanding line-height and vertical-align CSS 2.1 properties

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

I have some questions relating to the visual content which can be seen in
the attachment (use CTRL-+ in Firefox to see enlarged visual content with
the code that generated it on the left hand side). Let us name the visual
content listed with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 from top to bottom.
I have several questions about this scenario, for instance:

A. How is line-height being measured for boxes containing just a single line
   and how does it combine with the box height (and any font properties) to produce
   the visual results?

B. How come in picture 1 there is some yellow space on the very top of the picture,
   (zoom in to see it) which is missing from picture 2 and 3? And where does this
   space come from, as I don't appear to have specified it anywhere. How come
   picture 1 touches the top of the box while pictures 2 and 3 don't?

C. How come the height of box 2 differs from the height of box 5 (and the height of
   box 3 differs from the height of box 6). After all, line-height is the same in
   both cases, and besides vertical-align being specified for the nested image,
   nothing else is different. So how does specifying vertical-align or not change
   the outer box's height?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: yellow; line-height: 200px;">
    <img src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span>
  </p>
  <p style="width: 200px; background: yellow; line-height: 100px;">
    <img src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  </p>
  <p style="width: 100px; background: yellow; line-height: 100px;">
    <img src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  </p>
  <hr />
  <p style="width: 200px; background: yellow; line-height: 399px;">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  </p>
   <p style="width: 200px; background: yellow; line-height: 100px;">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  </p>
  <p style="width: 100px; background: yellow; line-height: 100px;">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Six CSS rules and Six Corresponding Layouts]

The CSS 2.1 spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html in section 10.8.1 says:

> Note. When there is only one value of 'line-height' for all inline
>   boxes in a block container box and they are all in the same font (and
>   there are no replaced elements, inline-block elements, etc.), the
>   above will ensure that baselines of successive lines are exactly
>   'line-height' apart. This is important when columns of text in
>   different fonts have to be aligned, for example in a table.

D. OK so line-height is the height between the font baselines on different lines,
   thus contributing to space between lines. But what does this line-height do if
   there is only one line? I guess what the spec doesn't say is that when considering
   the very top line, the line-height will extend to the top of the container, creating
   extra space at the top.

E. Would it be correct to say that if I have an image on the line, the (font) baseline
   will be aligned to the  lower edge of the image's content box, i.e., the bottom of
   the image displayed in the box generated by the box model around the image?
   Or is it also possible to achieve other effects, and if so than how?

Thanks.

Comment: I've added the text AAA after each of the img tags in the html source file. I can then highlight the img tag name and use the Live view option in DreamWeaver CC by clicking on the Live button at the top and edit the vertical-alignment property in the properties panel. Dreamweaver is nice here because you can select the valid values from a list (unlike in firebug where you have to type everything in). I've experimented with the  baseline | sub | super | top | text-top | middle | bottom | text-bottom in example 4 above and can now see how this parameter works.

Comment: The reasoning in part D. is wrong. Please ignore it.

Comment: I've played around a little bit more using example 4. Part E is also wrong. When borders, margins, and padding are specified these are also taken into account. If vertical-align is set to baseline, which is the default, and an inline replaced element, say an image, appears along the text contained in that text line, than the bottom of the margin box will be aligned to the baseline.

Comment: Hello. I've figured out the answer to question B., perhaps someone else can improve on what I write below. First of all, the font baseline in scenario 1. is slightly lower than 100px from the top of the yellow box. Since the image is 100px tall, and by default is aligned to this baseline (which is a font metric specified in the font file used), some space appears on the top as displayed

Comment: As per the comment above, since the line-height is 100px, this also means there is another baseline just above the image, but no font can fit there. I find this odd.

Comment: Note that in case 1., since I cannot control the positioning of the baseline, I can specify something like <img style="vertical-align: 7px;" src="images/jellyfish.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> to move the image further up 7 pixels from the baseline, until it touches the top of the enclosing yellow box. However, I cannot find a way to move the baseline itself further up in the box (so that if I type some AAA text after the image, the text will still remain aligned to the baseline). Thanks.

Comment: Seems like baseline positioning is determined by font metrics which are extraneous to CSS, so it is not possible to reposition text vertically within a box (perhaps without resorting to the table-cell display type which can include other complications of its own). So we will have to wait till the alignment-adjust CSS3 property is implemented by browsers. Regards. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#alignment-adjust

Comment: As a final remark, we can see from figure 1, by attaching a height="200px" and varying to height="201px" which adds a pixel and stretches the yellow area by 1 pixel, that if line-height is set to 200px, the 200px will be split, in this case to 93px above the baseline, and 107px below the baseline, totalling to a net sum of 200px.

Comment: That goes for scenario 1 in the above image. As to scenario 2, originally the same splitting is done between pixels above the baseline, and pixels below the baseline, as in scenario 1. However, since the image is taller than the number of pixels above the baseline and the image is aligned to the baseline, what happens is that the area of the area inside the p element is expanded vertically to accomodate the image height (given that the control flow for the p element is the normal control flow). This answers question C.

Comment: ... so, after all that, do you have any questions still outstanding?

Comment: Yes, there is one thing I would like to ask. I would like to know, suppose I know the height of a div, and the filename corresponding to the font used within that div. Then were is the vertical position of the font's baseline specified. Supposedly, it is specified in the font. How can I open up a font file and take a look at this value? Thanks.

Comment: That should probably be a whole new question. It probably has a different answer for each different font format, ttf, otf, woff etc. [Type light](http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html) opens ttf and otf files and under "font metrics" shows several values that could be being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to answer this question in order to bring the discussion to an end
given that the answer to the details for this post can be found in the above comments.

Regards.

Comment: You'll want to move the details in the comments into the answer here instead since they answer your question.